# Excel - Match placeholder with valid value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, email

I want to make an editable email template where everyone can update the email and assign to which user they want to sent which email. The email templates are from another sheet. Every template has its own email ID.
[image]

I want to match the template with the table that contain all of the information needed. So, whenever user input the email ID, it will mapped the value with thee placeholder in the email template.[image]

So far, here is what I have been working on with the email template. But right now it just grab all of the value from the cell. Which is breakable whenever I add columns or rows.

```
   Sub Mail_with_outlook2()

   Dim mainWB As Workbook
   Dim otlApp As Object
   Dim olMail As Object
   Dim olMailItem As Object
   Dim Doc As Object
   Dim SendID
   Dim CCID
   Dim Subject
   Dim Body
   Dim WrdRng As Object
   Dim result
   Dim i As Long



   Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set olMail = otlApp.CreateItem(0)
   Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook

   SendID = mainWB.Sheets("Email Template").Range("C3").Value
   CCID = mainWB.Sheets("Email Template").Range("D3").Value
   Subject = mainWB.Sheets("Email Template").Range("E3").Value
   Body = mainWB.Sheets("Email Template").Range("F3").Value


   Dim splitBody
   splitBody = Split(Body, "<%")

   For i = 0 To UBound(splitBody)

    result = Replace(Body, ">", "K")

   Next i


   With olMail
   .to = SendID
   If CCID <> "" Then
    .CC = CCID
   End If
  .Subject = Subject
  .Display
   End With
   Set Doc = olMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
   Set WrdRng = Doc.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)
   WrdRng.Select
   mainWB.Sheets("Email Template").Range("F3").Copy
   WrdRng.Paste

    MsgBox ("you Mail has been sent to " & SendID)
   End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to make the *Template sheet* more flexible, so you can add columns and VBA will still get the right value? It is not clear to me what is your question.

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to edit email template just by defining the placeholder and whenever I assign email ID in another sheet. It will replace the value with valid value within the row

Answer (score 1):

### Table + Match function

Consider turning your template sheet data into Excel Table. Then you can use the "table object" aka. `ListObject` to refer to it's columns by their name (column headings).

To find the relative position of the ID inside the table, you can use `WorksheetFunction.Match`.

### Code with examples

In my code, the sheet where the parameters for the mail template are is called "IssueTemplates".
The table is called "IssueTemplatesTable".

```
Sub GetDataFromTable()
    Dim IssueTemplatesTable As ListObject
    Dim ID_Searched As Integer 'Input variable
    Dim ID_RelativeRow As Integer 'Input relative row inside the table
    Dim Var1 As String 'Output variable

    Set IssueTemplatesTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IssueTemplates").ListObjects("IssueTemplatesTable")

    '''''''''''''''''EXAMPLE 1'''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ID_Searched = 17 'Input: "No" of template
    With IssueTemplatesTable
        ID_RelativeRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(ID_Searched, .ListColumns("No").DataBodyRange, 0)
        Var1 = .DataBodyRange(ID_RelativeRow, .ListColumns("Issue Type").Index)
    End With 'IssueTemplatesTable

    MsgBox Var1 'Output: "Others"

    '''''''''''''''''EXAMPLE 2'''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ID_Searched = 25 'Input: "No" of template
    With IssueTemplatesTable
        ID_RelativeRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(ID_Searched, .ListColumns("No").DataBodyRange, 0)
        Var1 = .DataBodyRange(ID_RelativeRow, .ListColumns("Issue Type").Index)
    End With 'IssueTemplatesTable

    MsgBox Var1 'Output: "Mapping"
End Sub
```